# Save url to string nightwatch

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm automating QA testing for a marketing sim. I'm using BrowserStack and Nightwatch in node.js

I want to jump to a specific webpage during a run - trouble is, there is a unique course code that will change with each test run within the URL (eg. .../8759309/...). This course code stays constant throughout all the pages I want to go to. In this example, I want to save the current URL (www.domain.com/8759309/page-i-have) to a string so that I can insert the course code and jump to the next page (www.domain.com/8675309/page-i-want).

There seems to be a function in protractor for this (browser.getCurrentUrl()) but I can't seem to find one for NightWatch.

My question is, does such a function exist in NightWatch, and if not, can you think of any workarounds?

Comment: If you know the domain, the course #, and the name of the final page... is there some reason you can't put those three together and make the URL from scratch?

Comment: That's just it, I won't know the course code, since it changes every time.

Comment: My guess is that you can get it from parsing a link on the page that contains the course code, e.g. get the href from an A tag and parse out the course #.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way in Nightwatch but you didn't notice that, simply use **browser.url()** without argument but a callback can get the current URL.

```
var savedUrl='';
browser.url(function(result){
  savedUrl=result;
})
```

Check the api for details:
http://nightwatchjs.org/api#url

Comment: How can I use this variable outside the function scope?

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch doesn't have that kind of a command built in. Since it sounds like you'd be using that functionality a lot, what I would do is write a javascript command to do that work, for you. you could even call it `.getCurrentUrl`. There's some documentation on creating custom commands, here: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands

You could try using `window.location.href` to retrieve the url of the window, then save it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to dereference the value

```
var savedUrl='';
browser.url(function(result){
  savedUrl=result.value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use [.perform()](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html) to be able to use the current url variable.

```js
let currentUrl;
browser.url(function(result) {
  currentUrl = result.value;
});
browser.perform(done => {
  console.log(currentUrl);
  done();
});
```